# Hadoop Map-Reduce: what you can tell about a state: mappers: 80%, reducers: 20%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

on interview I was asked a question: what you can tell about a state: mappers: 80%, reducers: 20% ?

My understanding is that it's impossible to get into that state. Because before reducers can start their job, all mappers should finished running: collect all key-value pairs and group them by key.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducers at 20 percent means that background threads have started to copy data from mapper output locations to reducer input locations. That's why reducers progress show as 20 percent before the mapper output reaches 100 percent.

Answer (score 2):

> before reducers can start their job, all mappers should finished
>   running

NO.

Shuffle starts as you mappers complete.. like in your example 80% map and 20% reduce means shuffle phase is in progress.

Reduce phase has three sub-phases:

1. shuffle
2. sort
3. reduce

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible, as the reducers are in the *shuffle* phase, so your answer was not correct. It would be impossible to reach a state in which reduce is more than 33% before the map has finished:

Roughly speaking, think of *shuffling*, *sorting*, and *reducing*, each as 1/3 of the reduce phase. Sorting and reducing cannot start before the map phase finishes, but shuffling (copying data) can. 
So, you cannot have more than 1/3 (33%) of the reduce phase finished before the map phase finishes.

You can set at which percentage of the mappers completion reducers will start copying, by setting the value of a parameter called reduce slowstart.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers can start working even if your Mappers are not done yet. Actually that is why you see reducers state 20% even before mappers are 100% but a reducer state can be 0%-33% while mappers are not done yet. i hope it helps